# Left Join most recent record, if one exists

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relationship

I have a table of people, and I want to pull the most recent record of event, but there may not be one.

So my problem is that even though I'm left joining to make sure I'm getting a record for each person, I'm only bringing back people that have events because I'm pulling the Max of a date as a criteria.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_people
LEFT JOIN tbl_events ON
    tbl_people.People_UID = tbl_events.People_UID
WHERE tbl_people.Active = 1
AND (
    SELECT MAX(Event_Date) FROM tbl_events
    )
```

Table **People** would have the following

```
People_UID
```

Table **Events** would have the following

```
Event_UID, People_UID, Event_Name, Event_Date
```

Like I said, what I'd like is an output like this:

```
Jen, Had a Baby, 7/10/2015
Shirley
Susan
Megan, Had a Baby, 8/5/2014
etc.
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What database are you using? It might affect the possible answers due to different functionality.

Comment: MySQL on a LAMP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a correlated subquery in the join that checks that there doesn't exists any event for the same person with a later date:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_people p
LEFT JOIN tbl_events e 
    ON p.People_UID = e.People_UID 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM tbl_Events 
       WHERE e.People_UID = People_UID 
         AND Event_Date > e.Event_Date
    )
WHERE p.Active = 1
```

It might not be the most efficient solution though; maybe limiting the left joined set first is better. (Or come to think of it the exists should be better).

Given a sample data set like:

```
People_UID  Event_UID   People_UID  Event_Name          Event_Date
Jen         1           Jen         Had a Baby          2015-07-10
Jen         3           Jen         Bought a horse      2013-07-10
Shirley     NULL        NULL        NULL                NULL
Susan       NULL        NULL        NULL                NULL
Megan       2           Megan       Had a Baby          2014-08-05
Megan       4           Megan       Had another Baby    2015-08-05
```

This would be the result:

```
People_UID  Event_UID   People_UID  Event_Name          Event_Date
Jen         1           Jen         Had a Baby          2015-07-10
Shirley     NULL        NULL        NULL                NULL
Susan       NULL        NULL        NULL                NULL
Megan       4           Megan       Had another Baby    2015-08-05
```

Using joins it could look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_people p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT e.* 
    FROM tbl_events e 
    JOIN (
       SELECT PEOPLE_UID, MAX(EVENT_DATE) MDATE 
       FROM tbl_Events GROUP BY People_UID
    ) A ON A.MDATE = E.event_date AND e.People_UID = A.People_UID 
) B ON p.People_UID = b.People_UID 
WHERE p.Active = 1
```

Comment: looks like this worked for me and seemed pretty simple.  Sorry the delayed response!  I had a kidney stone after posting this, and was out of pocket for a few days =(

Comment: @uofarob Ouch, hope you're better now!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
(  SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by tbl_people.name order by tbl_events.Event_Date desc) as rn 
     FROM tbl_people
     LEFT JOIN tbl_events 
       ON tbl_people.People_UID = tbl_events.People_UID
    WHERE tbl_people.Active = 1 ) t 
where t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database.

If you're using MySQL, you could simply put the correlated subquery into the on clause of the outer join like this:

```
select *
  from tbl_people p
  left join tbl_events_latest e
    on p.people_uid = e.people_uid
   and e.event_date =
       (select max(x.event_date) from tbl_events x where x.people_uid = e.people_uid)
 where p.active = 1
```

In other databases, that might not be so. For example, in Oracle, you'd get an error. You could alternatively run:

```
with tbl_events_latest as
 (select *
    from tbl_events e
   where event_date = ( select max(x.event_date)
                          from tbl_events x
                         where x.people_uid = e.people_uid ) )
select *
  from tbl_people p
  left join tbl_events_latest e
    on p.people_uid = e.people_uid
 where p.active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `Sql Server` you can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_people p
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 Event_Date 
            FROM tbl_events e
            WHERE p.People_UID = e.People_UID
            ORDER BY Event_Date DESC)oa
WHERE p.Active = 1
```

Or if you want to select just date then:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_people p
OUTER APPLY(SELECT MAX(Event_Date) AS Event_Date 
            FROM tbl_events e
            WHERE p.People_UID = e.People_UID)oa
WHERE p.Active = 1
```